# if/else condition on same line not working

Tags: java, return, conditional-statements, if-statement

Why doesnt this work?

```
if (condition) stuff; return;
else otherStuff;
```

or this

```
if (condition) stuff; return;
else {otherStuff;}
```

I can easily fix this with:

```
if (condition) {stuff; return;}
else otherStuff;
```

but I thought that the if statement block entire line not excluding return.

Comment: no, the block is until the 1st semicolon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because with:

```
if (condition) stuff; return;
else otherstuff;
```

The `if` conditional has a single statement, `stuff`.

It's followed by an unrelated `return` statement.

The `else` is stranded on its own, which isn't legal Java.

Semicolons are statement terminators, not EOLs. In order for a statement to be a block, it must be surrounded by `{}`, otherwise the statement ends at the `;`.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to expand on the above answer [[Dave Newton]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton).

*You can only use the syntax without brackets if you only have a single statement*. So, this is valid:

Code:

```
if (expression)
   statement;
```

In the above, statement will be executed `if expression==true.`

In the below code, it will still work but not be what you expect:

Code:

```
if (expression)
   statement1; // only this is inside of the if
   statemen2; // this is outside your if statement
```

The statement2 will be treated outside of the scope of the if statement which throws off your if..else construct. Only statement1 is inside the if. If you want multiple statements to be executed within an if, use brackets (as the above poster mentioned) :

Code:

```
if (expression) {
   statement1; // both of these will be executed if the expression is true
   statement2;
}
```

So obviously,

```
if (condition) {stuff; return;}
else otherStuff;
```

will do your stuff.

Other reference : [Braces are your friend](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/if/30if-braces.html)

Comment: Actually, the `if` clause accepts only a single statement in all cases. That statement, however, can be a compound statement (technically still a single statement) formed by enclosing a sequence of statements in braces.

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks are treated as any other white space by the Java compiler. You can't change the syntax of your program by putting things on the same line. In your first two examples, you seem to want the compiler to make the the two statements `stuff; return;` into a single compound statement associated with the `if` part of your `if/else`. That's exactly what the braces (`{}`) are for.